# MuleSoft - pass a multipart string as payload

Tags: multipart, dataweave, mulesoft

I have a multipart payload that I want to pass to a flow (an HTTP Listener):

```
--------=_Part_1_5138113571742769845
Content-Type: text/xml
Content-ID: <mm7-submit>

<soap:Envelope
  xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
  xmlns="http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/archive/23_series/23.140/schema/REL-5-MM7-1-2">
  ...
</soap:Envelope>

--------=_Part_1_5138113571742769845
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="------=_Part_2_3815517668157287202"
Content-ID: <attachment>

--------=_Part_2_3815517668157287202
Content-Type: text/plain; name=text1.txt
Content-ID: <text1.txt>
Content-Location: bundled/text1.txt

This is the text part I want to access

--------=_Part_2_3815517668157287202
Content-Type: image/png
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-ID: <image.png>
Content-Location: bundled/image.jpg

aGk=

--------=_Part_2_3815517668157287202--
--------=_Part_1_5138113571742769845--
```

When I send this payload using SoapUI, I can access the text part as `payload.parts.part1.content.parts.part0.content`.

How can I accomplish this with MuleSoft's tools (e.g. DataWeave expressions)? I want to be able to pass this payload from MUnit Set Event, which accepts DataWeave expressions and other formats.

I found the [multipart page](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dataweave-formats-multipart) in DataWeave's documentation, but it shows how to convert other formats to multipart, whereas I have the multipart payload already, I just need to pass it to the flow in a way that it can parse.

I also tried to simply paste it in a DataWeave expression:

```
%dw 2.0
output multipart/form-data boundary="------=_Part_1_5138113571742769845"
---
--------=_Part_1_5138113571742769845
Content-Type: text/xml
...
```

But when it tried to evaluate `payload.parts.part1.content.parts.part0.content`, I got the error:

> Message               : "javax.mail.internet.ParseException - Missing
> start boundary

Although I did specify the boundary. Am I missing something?

EDIT: I am using munit-runner version 2.3.9. The "Execution" part of the MUnit test case only has a Set Event and a Flow-ref (to the HTTP Listener, where I just try to log `payload.parts.part1.content.parts.part0.content`).

The Set Event has "Start with an empty event" ticked, in the Payload tab under Value it has the DataWeave expression, under Media Type it has "multipart/form-data",

in the Attributes tab it has the headers:

```
"headers": {
    "accept-encoding": "gzip,deflate",
    "content-type": "multipart/related; boundary=\"------=_Part_1_5138113571742769845\"; type=\"text/xml\"; start=\"<mm7-submit>\"",
    "host": "localhost:8081",
    "connection": "Keep-Alive",
    "user-agent": "Apache-HttpClient/4.5.5 (Java/16.0.1)"
  }
```

EDIT 2: The full error trace is:

```
ERROR 2022-10-31 11:39:08,780 [[MuleRuntime].uber.12:
[poc7].api-main.CPU_LITE @3bf5d6df]
org.mule.runtime.core.internal.exception.OnErrorPropagateHandler: 
******************************************************************************** Message               : "javax.mail.internet.ParseException - Missing
start boundary javax.mail.internet.ParseException: Missing start
boundary    at
javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart.parse(MimeMultipart.java:656)     at
javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart.getCount(MimeMultipart.java:312)  at
org.mule.weave.v2.module.multipart.MultiPartReader.doRead(MultiPartReader.scala:119)
    at org.mule.weave.v2.module.reader.Reader.read(Reader.scala:35)     at
org.mule.weave.v2.module.reader.Reader.read$(Reader.scala:33)   at
org.mule.weave.v2.module.multipart.MultiPartReader.read(MultiPartReader.scala:46)
    at
org.mule.weave.v2.el.MuleTypedValue.value(MuleTypedValue.scala:147)
    at
org.mule.weave.v2.model.values.wrappers.DelegateValue.valueType(DelegateValue.scala:17)
    at
org.mule.weave.v2.model.values.wrappers.DelegateValue.valueType$(DelegateValue.scala:16)
    at
org.mule.weave.v2.el.MuleTypedValue.valueType(MuleTypedValue.scala:177)
    at org.mule.weave.v2.model.types.ObjectType$.accepts(Type.scala:1068)
    at
org.mule.weave.v2.interpreted.node.executors.BinaryOverloadedStaticExecutor.findMatchingFunction(BinaryOverloadedStaticExecutor.scala:151)
    at
org.mule.weave.v2.interpreted.node.executors.BinaryOverloadedStaticExecutor.executeBinary(BinaryOverloadedStaticExecutor.scala:78)
    at
org.mule.weave.v2.interpreted.node.ChainedBinaryOpNode.doExecute(ChainedBinaryOpNode.scala:37)
    at
org.mule.weave.v2.interpreted.node.ValueNode.execute(ValueNode.scala:26)
    at
org.mule.weave.v2.interpreted.node.ValueNode.execute$(ValueNode.scala:21)
    at
org.mule.weave.v2.interpreted.node.ChainedBinaryOpNode.execute(ChainedBinaryOpNode.scala:7)
    at
org.mule.weave.v2.interpreted.node.NullSafeNode.doExecute(NullSafeNode.scala:14)
    at
org.mule.weave.v2.interpreted.node.ValueNode.execute(ValueNode.scala:26)
    at
org.mule.weave.v2.interpreted.node.ValueNode.execute$(ValueNode.scala:21)
    at
org.mule.weave.v2.interpreted.node.NullSafeNode.execute(NullSafeNode.scala:8)
    at
org.mule.weave.v2.interpreted.node.structure.DocumentNode.doExecute(DocumentNode.scala:26)
    at
org.mule.weave.v2.interpreted.node.ValueNode.execute(ValueNode.scala:26)
    at
org.mule.weave.v2.interpreted.node.ValueNode.execute$(ValueNode.scala:21)
    at
org.mule.weave.v2.interpreted.node.structure.DocumentNode.execute(DocumentNode.scala:11)
    at
org.mule.weave.v2.interpreted.InterpretedMappingExecutableWeave.$anonfun$writeWith$3(InterpreterMappingCompilerPhase.scala:264)
    at
org.mule.weave.v2.module.writer.WriterHelper$.writeValue(Writer.scala:161)
    at
org.mule.weave.v2.module.writer.WriterHelper$.writeAndGetResult(Writer.scala:139)
    at
org.mule.weave.v2.interpreted.InterpretedMappingExecutableWeave.writeWith(InterpreterMappingCompilerPhase.scala:264)
    at
org.mule.weave.v2.el.WeaveExpressionLanguageSession.evaluateLogExpression(WeaveExpressionLanguageSession.scala:330)
  [...]
    at
reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2205)
    at
reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMapMany$FlatMapManyMain.onSubscribe(MonoFlatMapMany.java:134)
    at
reactor.core.publisher.MonoCurrentContext.subscribe(MonoCurrentContext.java:35)
    at
reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMapMany.subscribe(MonoFlatMapMany.java:52)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext.subscribe(MonoNext.java:40)  at
reactor.core.publisher.MonoOnErrorResume.subscribe(MonoOnErrorResume.java:44)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoMap.subscribe(MonoMap.java:52)    at
reactor.core.publisher.MonoMap.subscribe(MonoMap.java:52)   at
reactor.core.publisher.MonoSubscriberContext.subscribe(MonoSubscriberContext.java:47)
    at
reactor.core.publisher.MonoSubscriberContext.subscribe(MonoSubscriberContext.java:47)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:3873)    at
reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(FluxFlatMap.java:420)
    at
reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeekFuseable.java:204)
    at
reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeekFuseable.java:204)
    at
reactor.core.publisher.FluxPublishOn$PublishOnSubscriber.runAsync(FluxPublishOn.java:447)
    at
reactor.core.publisher.FluxPublishOn$PublishOnSubscriber.run(FluxPublishOn.java:534)
    at reactor.core.scheduler.WorkerTask.call(WorkerTask.java:84)   at
reactor.core.scheduler.WorkerTask.call(WorkerTask.java:37)  at
java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)  at
org.mule.service.scheduler.internal.AbstractRunnableFutureDecorator.doRun(AbstractRunnableFutureDecorator.java:151)
    at
org.mule.service.scheduler.internal.RunnableFutureDecorator.run(RunnableFutureDecorator.java:54)
    at
java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at
java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834), while reading
`payload` as MultiPart. Trace:   at main (Unknown)" evaluating
expression: "payload.parts.part1.content.parts.part0.content". Element
: api-main/processors/2 @ poc7:poc7.xml:20 (Copy_of_Text_Logger)
Element DSL           : <logger level="INFO"
doc:name="Copy_of_Text_Logger"
doc:id="3672afde-5a7c-4745-bd78-540d726e9354" message="Received text:
#[payload.parts.part1.content.parts.part0.content]"></logger> Error type            : MULE:EXPRESSION FlowStack             : at
api-main(api-main/processors/2 @ poc7:poc7.xml:20
(Copy_of_Text_Logger))

  (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for
everything)
********************************************************************************
```

And the test XML is:

```
<munit:test name="poc7-test-suite-api-mainTest" doc:id="f625b0a6-55a7-431a-962f-cbc68587dca7" description="Test" expectedErrorType="ANY">
        <munit:execution >
            <munit:set-event doc:name="Set Event" doc:id="2fe9a6bc-b65d-4477-b705-010f247cec6f" >
                <munit:payload value='%dw 2.0
output multipart/form-data
ns soap http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/
---
{
  parts: {
    part0: {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "text/xml",
        "Content-ID": "&lt;mm7-submit&gt;"
      },
      content: {
        soap#Envelope: "\n  ...\n"
      }
    },
    part1: {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "multipart/mixed; boundary=\"------=_Part_2_3815517668157287202\"",
        "Content-ID": "&lt;attachment&gt;"
      },
      content: {
        parts: {
          part0: {
            headers: {
              "Content-Type": "text/plain; name=text1.txt",
              "Content-ID": "&lt;text1.txt&gt;",
              "Content-Location": "bundled/text1.txt"
            },
            content: "This is the text part I want to access\n"
          },
          part1: {
            headers: {
              "Content-Type": "image/png",
              "Content-Transfer-Encoding": "base64",
              "Content-ID": "&lt;image.png&gt;",
              "Content-Location": "bundled/image.jpg"
            },
            content: "hi"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}' mediaType="multipart/form-data" />
                <munit:attributes value="#[{&quot;headers&quot;: {
    &quot;accept-encoding&quot;: &quot;gzip,deflate&quot;,
    &quot;content-type&quot;: &quot;multipart/related; boundary=\&quot;------=_Part_1_5138113571742769845\&quot;; type=\&quot;text/xml\&quot;; start=\&quot;&lt;mm7-submit&gt;\&quot;&quot;,
    &quot;host&quot;: &quot;localhost:8081&quot;,
    &quot;connection&quot;: &quot;Keep-Alive&quot;,
    &quot;user-agent&quot;: &quot;Apache-HttpClient/4.5.5 (Java/16.0.1)&quot;
  }
}]" />
            </munit:set-event>
            <flow-ref doc:name="Flow-ref to api-main" doc:id="75a9f728-f461-4233-a5b2-1a01d7b21e80" name="api-main"/>
        </munit:execution>
        <munit:validation >
            <munit-tools:assert-equals message="Wrong HTTP Status code:" expected="#[746]" actual="#[message.inboundProperties['http.status']]" doc:name="Assert Equals"/>
        </munit:validation>
    </munit:test>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrapping the payload with `#[]` in MUnit Set Event solved the problem.

So the only required change from what I wrote in the question was in `Set Event -> Payload tab -> Value`.

Change from:

```
%dw 2.0
output multipart/form-data
---
[DataWeave expression]
```

To:

```
#[
%dw 2.0
output multipart/form-data
---
[DataWeave expression]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

To generate a multi part output just write the structure that you want in DataWeave, and use the correct output format. Don't try to paste in the script things that are not in DataWeave. Except maybe for JSON, which is similar enough.

I parsed your input and output it to JSON, then used that as the script. I removed some unneeded quotes from the keys, but left the required ones for names with the hyphen character. Then I added a namespace declaration for SOAP. You can use DataWeave features for the rest.

Example:

```js
%dw 2.0
output multipart/form-data
ns soap http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/
---
{
  parts: {
    part0: {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "text/xml",
        "Content-ID": "<mm7-submit>"
      },
      content: {
        soap#Envelope: "\n  ...\n"
      }
    },
    part1: {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "multipart/mixed; boundary=\"------=_Part_2_3815517668157287202\"",
        "Content-ID": "<attachment>"
      },
      content: {
        parts: {
          part0: {
            headers: {
              "Content-Type": "text/plain; name=text1.txt",
              "Content-ID": "<text1.txt>",
              "Content-Location": "bundled/text1.txt"
            },
            content: "This is the text part I want to access\n"
          },
          part1: {
            headers: {
              "Content-Type": "image/png",
              "Content-Transfer-Encoding": "base64",
              "Content-ID": "<image.png>",
              "Content-Location": "bundled/image.jpg"
            },
            content: "hi"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

```
------=_Part_5779_1231291611.1666866442792
Content-Type: text/xml
Content-ID: <mm7-submit>
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="part0"

<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  ...
</soap:Envelope>
------=_Part_5779_1231291611.1666866442792
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="------=_Part_2_3815517668157287202"
Content-ID: <attachment>
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="part1"

--------=_Part_2_3815517668157287202
Content-Type: text/plain; name=text1.txt
Content-ID: <text1.txt>
Content-Location: bundled/text1.txt

This is the text part I want to access

--------=_Part_2_3815517668157287202
Content-Type: image/png
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-ID: <image.png>
Content-Location: bundled/image.jpg

hi
--------=_Part_2_3815517668157287202--

------=_Part_5779_1231291611.1666866442792--
```

Comment: I tried this, and I am still getting the same error ("Missing start boundary") when I pass this as the payload from MUnit Set Event. However, I tried to set a variable ("tempvar") to this expression, and then evaluate `#[vars.tempvar.parts.part1.content.parts.part0.content]`, and it did work. So maybe it is an MUnit issue?

Comment: It could be. You should share the details of how you are using the transformation in MUnit. Otherwise the question is not complete.

Comment: Since the answer seems to work for the question as asked, you should ask a new question for the MUnit issue.

Comment: But the question explicitly states "I want to be able to pass this payload from MUnit Set Event", and the error message I wrote in the question (which is also received from the solution in your answer) is from MUnit Set Event...

Comment: Then add all details of what you are doing in Munit and versions.

Comment: Added the version and details, please let me know if additional information is needed.

Comment: Please add the XML for the MUnit test case and the complete error information from the log, not just the error message. If there is a stack trace also that.

Comment: Added the test XML. The full error trace was too long for the message, so I kept the head and the tail, I hope it is OK.

Comment: You should not use quote format for logs or code.

Comment: OK, I updated it to code format now. So do you know why I get the error message?